# How to detect if a cell has been modified in Ext JS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I was wondering if it is possible in Ext JS to detect in a grid whether or not a cell, knowing its position (row and column index), has been modified, that is, when the red flag appears on the top-left corner.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of extjs are you using?

Comment: 6.0.2 Classic version

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the edit event on the cellediting plugin.
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing.html#event-edit

In the docs you'll notice that the context parameter has the information you are looking for.

Comment: It is true that we can pass on the row and column indexes as a parameter for the event but the problem is, I need to know the state of the cells when they are not in edit mode, and thus when the CellEditing plugin is closed.